# How can I make a good impression, as a new player, when joining an established group?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, dragonborn

So I've been watching 4 friends play D&D for a little over a year now. It's finally my time to join and become a part of all the fun! But I'm nervous. I have my character. Dragonborn Druid (circle of the Shepard) starting with 39 HP.  WIS and CON are my high points and everything else is fairly evened out.
Any ways.... they're about to begin a fight where I will jump in and help them fight the "bad guys". I'm actually overly excited about this, but I'm not as good with RPGs as it is.
Any tips on my first session?  My husband is the DM but he won't give me any tips as he sees this as a great way to express my character and what I do in my own way, which is awesome and makes sense. But I just need a few tips on how to keep things interesting.

I'm a down to earth dragon druid who really just wants peace with all living things, but a bad ass who will stop at nothing to protect the innocent!

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jessica, take the [tour] when you have a moment. This sort of open ended discussion question is outside the scope of what we handle on this site, however, we have a [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) where your question may be on topic.

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want to make a big splashy entry into a fight? What Druid Circle are you playing, and what level are you currently?

Comment: People who are inviting a new player to join are (hopefully) going into it with the expectation that they'll be guiding you through understanding the game's mechanics and rules for the first few sessions. Don't stress too much.

Comment: @From - yes, pretty much lol. I did the circle of the Shepard. And level 3

Comment: @Michael - thank you! That's what I'm hoping for! But as long as I've been sitting in and just watching them play...they've always been inviting and begging me to play. So it's a lot of pressure now to keep them excited to have me. If that makes sense? 

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I'm aware and I've done the tour ☺️ honestly, me asking this question...I dont really see an issue as I am trying to get some insight on what to expect and where one might end up. It seemed a good way to also find out if others have been in similar situations, and have some advice! If it doesn't meet guidelines, I'll take it down. But I honestly didn't see an issue, I'm sorry!

Comment: @JessicaLynn noooo don't take it down. We just need to mold this I to something where you get the best help. We might close it first so you don't get a confusing barrage of half-help/half-opinion posts that aren't focused. When we understand more specifically what you need tips on we can re-open it and start getting answers for you.

Comment: Like maybe this will get you more help if it was called "How can I make a good impression, as a new player, when joining an established group". Then you're less likely to get unhelpful tips?

Comment: Also worth considering, are you looking for social tips, roleplaying tips, rule tips, using powers and abilities. Each of those may attract different types of answer.

Comment: Hmm...would your Dungeon Master be amenable to tailoring the situation to fit your druid? Do you know what Classes the other players are playing?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - that's actually not a bad idea! I may use that if you don't mind!

Comment: @SeriousBri honestly, role-playing tips mostly and maybe some social tips (because I'm not exactly sure what a social tip might be!) Hahaha

Comment: @From I am playing with a robot, teifling, and druid warlock! I'm sure he could find a great way to fit me in. So far, I'll just basically be joining in with the fight that they're already in. Except I'll be invisibily there and then appear after the last ones killed. Lol so exciting to see where it goes

Comment: Wait, hang on, do I understand this correctly - you won't actually participate in the fight, but will make your entrance once it's already over?

Comment: @JessicaLynn of course, no need to ask. In fact I can [edit] that for you this time.

Comment: @From - yes, and I did. But I had a secret with me for them after the fight. The beast they fought that they thought they killed is actually still alive! They will have to fight him again at some point, so I will join them in there journey and help them through the woods/forest- of course if they in return get me back into the world of the living (I've hid in the woods for 20 years, hiding from society, d/t my family their criminal past) its so much to explain and hard to fit it all here lol. But I will say this was an absolute blast! I had so much fun! We meet again in 1 week ☺️

Comment: I appreciate ALL of the tips here and the interest! @From - you really help make this fun and gave me a lot of great ideas! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage you are a true friend and I thank you from the bottom of my heart- thanks for the gentle guidance- I cannot wait to post an actual question here soon that will be easier for ppl to answer! Stsy tuned, I know I'll need you guys soon enough 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are joining a group where you have already kibitzed for a year, I won't bother discussing the social details that could arise. You should know them and their playstyle fairly well, and they should be at least somewhat familiar with you already. I'd generally advise trying to **fit into the group dynamic** over "winning" at the game, or even making your mark, first.

A memorable character entrance for *your character* could be achieved in a number of ways, here is what my lacking imagination comes up with:

### Save them!

If the party is running out of hitpoints (getting damaged) or are unable to get good hits in, you could use one of your **Spirit Totems**.

- **Hawk Spirit** is excellent at giving the melee combatants that extra oomph that may be needed for solid hits. Pair with a casting of **Enlarge** on one of the party's melee combatants, and the combat should soon be over.
- **Unicorn Spirit** is an excellent defensive and heal-booster. In particular, it (arguably, check with DM) has wonderful synergy with the 2nd level Druid spell **Healing Spirit**, which will trigger the healing effect of the Unicorn Spirit every round for a number of rounds based on your WIS.

### Finish the fight!

If the enemy isn't too strong, or maybe there are a few of them, a well-placed **Breath Weapon** attack, which does damage partially based on your CON, could finish off a rather large horde - which is darn impressive at level 3. You have some spells (**Wither and Bloom**, **Moonbeam**, etc) which could likewise inflict some hurt.

### Weaken the enemy!

You have quite a few options here. If the enemy have metal weapons or armor, there's the excellent **Heat Metal** spell which will cause damage and/or force them to abandon their equipment. **Faerie Fire** could be an option, but your **Hawk Spirit** is better. Cast Reduce on the enemy to give them a Disadvantage on Strength checks (and lower damage), after first activating **Bear Spirit** to give the party a corresponding Advantage.

### Paint the battlefield Druid!

One of the primary roles of a Druid is battlefield control. You have a number of spells (**Entangle**, **Spike Growth**, etc...) which should be able to put multiple enemies in a bad situation, and a few (**Hold Person**, **Earthbind**, etc...) for single enemies. **Enlarge** the already large enemy so it can no longer move freely. Cast spells (**Dust Devil**, **Flaming Sphere**, etc...) which make parts of the battlefield less inviting for enemy movement.

---

Note that these are all suggestions. You are a Druid, a Shepherd of Nature, and not limited by much except your own imagination (well, and your current level), and certainly shouldn't feel limited by mine. Check out the first three levels (Cantrips, 1st and 2nd) of the [Druid spell list](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spells:druid) and see if inspiration strikes.

**Whatever you go for**, any of my suggestions or anything else, remember to cast **Summon Beast** before you do anything else, **unless** you're planning on casting another spell which requires Concentration. Having an extra meatshield on the battlefield can make or break a fight, as can having an aerial combatant battering at enemy spellcasters.

If you have an idea, it is probably a good idea to discuss it with the DM first, and see if the situation or idea can be adjusted for a better fit. I am **quite** certain the DM will be happy to oblige.

Comment: Omg. I LOVE this. So I am going to use mold earth and entangled at first to show them I'm on their side

Comment: To visitors, if you want to downvote this answer, accepted by the question owner, please also give some feedback as to why. I am new here, and this is my first accepted answer, so I would like to better understand what the problem is.

Comment: @From don't worry about the downvotes, people will downvote anything, it's pretty rare here to find an answer that doesn't have any downvotes. I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer.